# Rich editor textarea wont hold data

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

I have a HTML page with some pre-set options this work fine when I use a plain HTML textarea,
but when I use a rich editor the textarea wont hold data, please see the demo pages.

Working page: [Here](http://bulk-email-store.com/works.htm)

Non working page: [Here](http://bulk-email-store.com/test.htm)

Comment: what's going wrong? I didn't get it

Comment: We'll need to see some code before we can help.

Comment: when I open both pages, they're similar. The second one (non working page) it's even more beautiful, with the editor, but none of them has anything inside the text area, unless I change the select box

Comment: I am able to see text in both cases. can you explain the issue clearly?

Comment: Can you add your code here because Its hard to say just by seeing your links

Comment: So what is your Qs? You are asking why is the 2nd one better than the first ? Is that so ?

Comment: On the Working page you can select & remove several images and canned text at a time on the non working one it only selects (holds) one option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code

```
$mydropdown.change(function(){
   nicEditors.findEditor("TextArea").setContent($mytextbox.val() + TextVars[$(this).val()]);
}); 

$("input[type='checkbox'][name*='ImageVar']").change(function () {
  var $chk = $(this);
  if ($chk.prop('checked')) {
    nicEditors.findEditor("TextArea").setContent($mytextbox.val() + ImageVars[$chk.attr('name')]);
  } else {
    nicEditors.findEditor("TextArea").setContent($mytextbox.val().replace(ImageVars[$chk.attr('name')], ""));
  }
});
```

to the following code

```
$mydropdown.change(function(){
   nicEditors.findEditor("TextArea").setContent(nicEditors.findEditor("TextArea").getContent() + TextVars[$(this).val()]);
}); 

$("input[type='checkbox'][name*='ImageVar']").change(function(){
   var $chk = $(this);
   if($chk.prop('checked')){
      nicEditors.findEditor("TextArea").setContent(nicEditors.findEditor("TextArea").getContent() + ImageVars[$chk.attr('name')]);
   }else{
      nicEditors.findEditor("TextArea").setContent(nicEditors.findEditor("TextArea").getContent().replace(ImageVars[$chk.attr('name')], ""));
   }
});
```

Comment: On the Working page you can select & remove several images and canned text at a time on the non working one it only selects (holds) one option.

Comment: So you want to append all texts selected?

Comment: Yes, just like the working one I need to be able to select several images or text and be able to remove any image or text.

Comment: pre-canned text is working but still need to be able to and remove multiple images like the working demo

Comment: can you update the latest code on server... what error are you getting?

Comment: Updated the code in my answer. Update it and it should work.. :)

Comment: Wolf, Server is updated but now I don't get anything in IE or FF.

Comment: Now you are missing the closing tag for `$(window).load(function(){`. Also remove the `//<![CDATA[` and `//]]>` in your script section.

Comment: Replace the last close tag `}` with `});`